# Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'contour'

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Hey I am facing issue I have also tried diff versions of opencv. IF someone can help me with this. Thanks

```
   import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

model1 = load_model('devanagari_model.h5')

def main():
    letter_count = {0: 'CHECK', 1: '01_ka', 2: '02_kha', 3: '03_ga', 4: '04_gha', 5: '05_kna', 6: 'character_06_cha',
                    7: '07_chha', 8: '08_ja', 9: '09_jha', 10: '10_yna',
                    11: '11_taamatar',
                    12: '12_thaa', 13: '13_daa', 14: '14_dhaa', 15: '15_adna', 16: '16_tabala', 17: '17_tha',
                    18: '18_da',
                    19: '19_dha', 20: '20_na', 21: '21_pa', 22: '22_pha',
                    23: '23_ba',
                    24: '24_bha', 25: '25_ma', 26: '26_yaw', 27: '27_ra', 28: '28_la', 29: '29_waw', 30: '30_motosaw',
                    31: '31_petchiryakha',32: '32_patalosaw', 33: '33_ha',
                    34: '34_chhya', 35: '35_tra', 36: '36_gya', 37: 'CHECK'}
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    Lower_green = np.array([110, 50, 50])
    Upper_green = np.array([130, 255, 255])
    pred_class=0
    pts = deque(maxlen=512)
    blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    digit = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, img = cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, Lower_green, Upper_green)
        blur = cv2.medianBlur(mask, 15)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur, (5, 5), 0)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
        center = None
        if len(cnts) >= 1:
            contou = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea(cnts))
            if cv2.contourArea(contou) > 250:
                ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contou)
                cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(img, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                M = cv2.moments(contou)
                center = (int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00']))
                pts.appendleft(center)
                for i in range(1, len(pts)):
                    if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                        continue
                    cv2.line(blackboard, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (255, 255, 255), 10)
                    cv2.line(img, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), 5)
        elif len(cnts) == 0:
            if len(pts) != []:
                blackboard_gray = cv2.cvtColor(blackboard, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                blur1 = cv2.medianBlur(blackboard_gray, 15)
                blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(blur1, (5, 5), 0)
                thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
                blackboard_cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[1]
                if len(blackboard_cnts) >= 1:
                    cnt = max(blackboard_cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
                    print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
                    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 2000:
                        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                        digit = blackboard_gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                        # newImage = process_letter(digit)
                        pred_probab, pred_class = keras_predict(model1, digit)
                        print(pred_class, pred_probab)

            pts = deque(maxlen=512)
            blackboard = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.putText(img, "Conv Network :  " + str(letter_count[pred_class]), (10, 470),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
        cv2.imshow("Contours", thresh)
        k = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k == 27:
            break

def keras_predict(model, image):
    processed = keras_process_image(image)
    print("processed: " + str(processed.shape))
    pred_probab = model.predict(processed)[0]
    pred_class = list(pred_probab).index(max(pred_probab))
    return max(pred_probab), pred_class


def keras_process_image(img):
    image_x = 32
    image_y = 32
    img = cv2.resize(img, (image_x, image_y))
    img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
    img = np.reshape(img, (-1, image_x, image_y, 1))
    return img


keras_predict(model1, np.zeros((32, 32, 1), dtype=np.uint8))
main()
```

> line 95, in 
> main()
> File "c:\HindiHandWritingRecognizer\application.py", line 37, in main
> contou = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea(cnts))
> TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'contour'
> [ WARN:0] terminating async callback

Comment: what do *you* think is the issue? you use the same idea multiple times in *your* code but in that one place you do it wrong. -- please review [ask]

Comment: Why do you called this? keras_predict

Comment: You need to debug your code. Change the affected line to `contou = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)`. You write the same line correctly elsewhere, but mistake it here. Please don't just blindly copy.